# $.ajax() joining two data objects

Tags: jquery, json

Lets say I want to join two data sets in my $.ajax call as such:

```
updateData: function(dataDetails) {
    $.ajax({
        url: './example.php',
        data: {
            lets:"GET",
            real:"funky"
        },
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",

    });
}
```

`dataDetails` in the function argument contains another set of data, such as...

```
{
    a:"1",
    b:"2",
    c:"3"
}
```

How should I declare this in my `data:` area of the `$.ajax()` if I want to join these sets?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the [`$.extend()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) utility should work here:

```
data: $.extend({
    lets:"GET",
    real:"funky"
}, dataDetails)
```

Answer (score 2):

the extend function is great for this, I think.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/

it merges the two objects recursively, *overwriting* some of the parameters of the first, if they are identical.

Answer (score 2):

as Yi Jiang suggested .extend will do the work. But to be on the safer side you can do this to recursively merge them:-

```
data: $.extend(true,{
    lets:"GET",
    real:"funky"
}, dataDetails)
```

Comment: While not necessarily suitable this is absolutely an important point to make. +1